# bootstrap.js throwing an undefined error only in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, twitter-bootstrap

I included the newest jQuery installation in my Magento theme, but then prototype.js was throwing an error because two jQuery files were being loaded I guess. I removed it and the prototype errors stopped popping up, however bootstrap is now throwing me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

And many people are saying it's because jQuery is not being loaded.
So then I load jQuery back in and then prototype throws these errors again (repeatedly):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5653
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734

So.. I'm getting confused on how to solve this exactly.. When I delete my jQuery.js file, those errors stop and then bootstrap throws an error.. but no other jQuery installation is being loaded from what I can see so that only makes sense bootstrap would throw an error. So then I just can't see why these errors are being thrown for prototype when most people say it's because two jQuery instances are being loaded.

Comment: Is bootstrap.js using `$`? If it's not already wrapped in `(function($) { //code here })(jQuery)`, bootstrap might be trying to call jQuery functions on prototype.js objects.

Comment: It starts off like this : !function(e){"use strict";e(function(){ and ends something like this : })}(window.jQuery);

I'm using almost the latest installation from like last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok FINALLY after a week of doing this since the other comment didn't make my problems go away.. this is seriously all I had to do:

I put this in a jquery-noconflict.js file : `jQuery.noConflict();` And added it in right after my jQuery.js file and everything is working fancy! =) And all these errors that I couldn't make go away for the past week disappeared as well =)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is known to not play nicely with Prototype.js. Try using the [bootstrap-prototype](https://github.com/jwestbrook/bootstrap-prototype) fork.

Comment: Ok how exactly do I implement that into my theme? There are loads of files and I'm unsure of which ones I need and what I need to put in my <head> tags for this to work..

Comment: Replace the bootstrap files you are currently using with their counterparts from the prototype.js fork. It looks like the whole thing was written for Magento, since no one else uses prototype anymore. Also, put the files in your layout xml, not directly in the `<head>`.

Comment: So just to be clear. Update the prototype.js with the bootstrap_prototype.js file?? Yes I am adding them in the layout xml.

Comment: Replace the default bootstrap library you're using with the bootstrap_prototype library. You'll need to leave prototype.js as is to keep Magento running smoothly.

Comment: Still getting these errors now:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WebkitTransition' of undefined bootstrap_prototype.min.js:27
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734

Comment: Do you know what object is triggering the type error? `attachEvent` and `dispatchEvent` are vanilla javascript -- not jQuery -- but they require that the event in reference be defined first. Is there any way you could post a fiddle or some code?

Comment: The error is coming from line 5,653 in prototype.js that Magento comes with.. This error was just here by default when I added Twitter Bootstrap. But when I take bootstrap away, it's saying undefined is not a function.. it's none of the code I wrote.. so I don't really know how to debug it.